# Merge HTML Files with Python

Tags: python, html, graph, merge, static

I have some HTML Files that are linked with relative paths. Like this:

```
<h1 id="languages">Languages</h1>
    <h2 id="python">Python</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./python">Python</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2 id="nodejs">NodeJS</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./nodejs">NodeJS</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I want replace the `./python` (`./python/index.html`) link with the content of the file. Doing this recursively. The same with all links in each file.

This is my example file structure

```
├── index.html
├── nodejs
│   └── index.html
├── python
└── └── index.html
```

How can I do that with Python?

I need to do this in order to generate a Table of contents of the hole content. These HTML files are generated with a RST to HTML convertor.

Comment: Seems like you should be addressing this before the conversion. [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/index.html) is built on top of RST and should be able to do this.

Comment: This is doable but not trivial, as you have to parse the HTML (DO NOT USE REGEX FOR THIS), then retrieve and insert the referenced file.  The nature of this means it will be recursive and will need to check for circular references to avoid infinite loops.  Explaining how to do all this is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: I am using BeautifulSoup for generate the table of contents. Thanks.